# Search pattern and print it on the line before (awk)

Tags: awk

I have this file :

```
>AX-89948491
CACCTTTT[C/T]ATTTCATTCCTAC
>AX-89940152
AGATGAGA[A/G]TAAAGCTTCTGTC
>AX-89922107
ACAGAAAT[G/T]TATAGATATTACT
```

I need to find the pattern "`[A-Z]/[A-Z]`" (it is necessarily present every two lines) ; and put it on the line before like this :

```
>AX-89948491-[C/T]
CACCTTTT[C/T]ATTTCATTCCTAC
>AX-89940152-[A/G]
AGATGAGA[A/G]TAAAGCTTCTGTC
>AX-89922107-[G/T]
ACAGAAAT[G/T]TATAGATATTACT
```

I did :

```
awk 'tmp=/\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/{if (a && a !~ /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/) print a"-"$tmp; print} {a=$0}' my_file
```

But that gives the entire line , not the pattern.

Any help?

Comment: it is a good practice not to allow invalid  chars in your regex  so `[ACGT]/[ACGT]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could print the previous line plus the current matched part of the pattern, and given that it is present every 2 lines:

```
awk '
match($0, /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/) {
  m = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  print prev "-" m ORS $0
}
{prev = $0}
' my_file
```

Output

```
>AX-89948491-[C/T]
CACCTTTT[C/T]ATTTCATTCCTAC
>AX-89940152-[A/G]
AGATGAGA[A/G]TAAAGCTTCTGTC
>AX-89922107-[G/T]
ACAGAAAT[G/T]TATAGATATTACT
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` program. Here is `tac` + `awk` + `tac` solution. Simple explanation would be using `tac` to print output in reverse lines order(from bottom to up) sending it to `awk` program to get `[[A-Z]/[A-Z]` and saving its matched value to `val` variable and printing that line, if `match` function doesn't have any matched regex value then printing that line(basically lines where we need to add `[[A-Z]/[A-Z]` value) along with `-` and val value. Now passing this output to `tac` again to get output in exact same format in which OP has shown us samples.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
  match($0,/\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    print
    next
  }
  {
    print $0"-"val
  }
' | tac
```